# How to pass information through a method and returning a value

Tags: java, function, methods

I'm new to Java, and need help. I have been asked to write a program that rolls dice and determines the chance of the player to get two "1s" on the top face of the dice. I have different functions such as role(), getTopFace() etc. I want to be get what the number on the dice is using these functions, but don't know how to call them in my main function. Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Random;
public class SnakeEyes {

        private final int sides;
    private int topFace;
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        String numberSides;
        int n;
        numberSides=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the number of sides on the dice:");
        n = Integer.parseInt ( numberSides);

        int[]die=new int[n];
        for (int index=0; index<n;index++)
        {
            die[index]=index+1;
        } 
                //Here is where I want to get information from my functions and calculate the ods of getting two 1's.

    }
    public void Die(int n)
    {
        if(n>0)
        {
            int sides=n;
            topFace=(int)(Math.random()*sides)+1;
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  " Die : precondition voliated");
        }
    }
    public int getTopFace(int topFace)
    {

        return topFace;
    }


    public int role(int[] die)
    {

        topFace=(int)(Math.random()*sides)+1;
        return topFace;

}
}
```

Comment: why does `role()` function take `topFace` argument?

Comment: Sorry that was actually a typo. Can you help solve my problem?

Comment: `private final int sides;` is never initialized(in constructor). So it's value is always 0.

Answer (score 0):

Make an object of your class `SnakeEyes` in your main method, and call the required functions using that object.

Example:

```
SnakeEyes diceObj = new SnakeEyes();
int topFace = diceObj.role(n,....);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call this functions from main this functions must be "static", because main its a static function and static function can only call other static functions.

But... this is a very ugly design for a java program, before jumping to write java code you need to understand at least a little about object orientation. For example, why you can't call a non-static function from a static function?, the answer of this question requires knowledge about object orientation and its a knowledge you need if you want to write serious java code.

Comment: I know that it's an ugly design, but I was given the structure. I am not allowed make up my own structure, which is why I am finding it hard to understand.

Comment: You can make this methods static and by the way recommend reading about OO to the one who give you this "structure".